# Convert Dotted lines to solid lines in latex

Tags: tables, excel

I want to display the following table in my Overleaf Latex File

[image: Table]

So I draw this table in the excel and using the excel AddsIn of "converExcelToLatex", I generated the following latex code

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|cccc|}
    \toprule
          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{  } & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Students}} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Sr No.}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Names}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Male}} & \textbf{Female} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{School} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{10} & 15 \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{College} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{10} & 25 \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{University} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{20} & 35 \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{Total} &       & \textbf{40} & \textbf{75} \\
          &       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{115}} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

So when I used this code into my overleaf latex page, I got following table

[image]

So you can see I am getting the dashed lines but I want the filled lines, How can I correct this?

Regards

Comment: Horizontal lines from the booktabs package are incompatible with vertical lines. This is why you observe small white gaps around the intersections.

Comment: If you wish to stick to using vertical and horizontal lines, use hline for every horizontal line. If you want to keep the lines from the booktabs package, remove all vertical lines.

Comment: @leandriis Thanks, but exactly where to put that hline can you please guide me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have done again from the beginning you code and excuse me...I have used `newtxtext` package the clone of Times New Roman as the image. Here there is a complete code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}                                               & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Students}}           \\ \hline
\textbf{Sr No.} & \textbf{Names}& \textbf{Male} & \textbf{Female} \\ \hline
1                                & School                          & 10                             & 15                               \\ \hline
2                                & College                         & 10                             & 25                               \\ \hline
3                                & University                      & 20                             & 35                               \\ \hline
\textbf{Total}  &                                 & \textbf{40} & \textbf{75}    \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{}                                             & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{115}}                \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer as it was really helpful and excuse me, I also have accepted your answer :)

Comment: @李慕 Don't worry about it. I don't care about votes, but to help people and especially to improve myself. Best regards.

Answer (score 5):

You can easily do such table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

In this environment, you define rectangular blocks (with `\Block`) and, with the key `hvlines`, all the rules will be drawn excepted in the blocks.

Remark: Prior version 5.0, we have to put `{CCCC}` instead of `{cccc}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{0.5ex}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}[hvlines]
\Block{1-2}{} & & \Block{1-2}{\textbf{Students}} \\
\textbf{Sr No.} & \textbf{Names} & \textbf{Male} & \textbf{Female} \\
1 & School & 10 & 15 \\
2 & College & 20 & 25 \\
3 & University & 20 & 35 \\
\Block{2-4}{}\textbf{Total} & & \textbf{40} & \textbf{75} \\
& & \Block{1-2}{\textbf{115}} 
\end{NiceTabular}


\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: This looks very good !

Comment: @李慕 Please can you give the check mark to F. Pantigny? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Sebastiano I cannot , because first of all it does not work  and second of all I like you , thats all!

Comment: There is a typo "Univertity" instead of "University" :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano: You are right. I have corrected.

Answer (score 4):

Here are two additional versions of your table. In the first one, I have replaced `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` with `\hline`. Additionally, I have used the `cellspace` package to allow for a slightly larger vertical space between text and lines. In the second table, I have used the horizontal lines from the `booktabs` package and removed all vertical lines:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[column=0]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{\tabcolsep}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{\cellspacetoplimit}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|0c|0c|0c|0c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|0c|}{}          & \multicolumn{2}{0c|}{\textbf{Students}} \\ \hline
\textbf{Sr No.} & \textbf{Names} & \textbf{Male} & \textbf{Female}         \\ \hline
1               & School         & 10            & 15                      \\ \hline
2               & College        & 10            & 25                      \\ \hline
3               & University     & 20            & 35                      \\ \hline
\textbf{Total}  &                & \textbf{40}   & \textbf{75}             \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|0l|}{}          & \multicolumn{2}{0c|}{\textbf{115}}       \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
       &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Students}  \\ \cmidrule{3-4}
Sr No. & Names & Male & Female \\ \midrule
1              & School       & 10    & 15     \\
2              & College      & 10    & 25     \\
3              & University   & 20    & 35     \\ \midrule
Total  &       & 40 & 75                       \\ \cmidrule{3-4}
       &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{115}       \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Beautiful work @leandriis

Comment: @李慕 Also this answer it is very good and not mine.